# Bulk replace text in all columns

Tags: openrefine

I am using OpenRefine to do some data preparation. I have dozens of columns that need to be cleaned with the same GREL expression `value.replace("text to be replaced","new text")`

How do bulk apply the GREL expression to all columns at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Supported since OpenRefine 2.7

Multi-column edit is supported via the "Transform All" feature - available since OpenRefine v2.7 Release

### Initial Answer:

Currently, OpenRefine doesn't support multiple column editing. However, you can make the edit on the first column and then edit the JSON code generated to apply it to other columns. You can read more about this process here: http://googlerefine.blogspot.ca/2012/06/google-refine-json-and-my-notepad-or.html